# Write to XML file using Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xml, cocoa, append, nsxmlparser

OK, I managed to read from an `XML` file using `NSXMLParser`, but now I don't know how to write to an `XML` file. I have an XML file, say:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<user id="abcd" password="pass1"/>
<user id="efg" password="pass2"/>
</root>
```

Now when a new user enters details, I want to store them in a new tag. Lets say like, the `id` is "**hhhh**" and `password` is "**pass3**".

I want to add a new tag with attributes as such:

```
<user id="hhhh" password="pass3"/>
```

to the XML file.

How should I do this? Please explain in an elaborate way. I am a newbie here. Any links to tutorials or examples will be much helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: i want to know how you solved this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [Tree-Based XML Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSXML_Concepts/NSXML.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001269). You might use NSXMLDocument and friends. You could also search the web for open-source alternatives (there are plenty that parse and a few that write). A quick Google search for "using NSXMLDocument" yields several third-party tutorials.

It's better that you read the documentation yourself first and ask more specific questions. Help us help you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [kissxml](https://github.com/robbiehanson/KissXML).

> The goal is to create an NSXML style API that can used in environments without NSXML (e.g. iPhone).
>
> KissXML was inspired by the TouchXML project, but was created to add full support for generating XML as well as supporting the entire NSXML API.
>
> Please support this free and open source project

[address](http://code.google.com/p/kissxml/)

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of really good third party XML parsers you can take a look at that will probably make it easier on you.

Here's a good post I found talking about them. http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project

Comment: Ray also has a post showing how to specifically use Google's GDataXML library. http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml